# rstudio color appearance, specific color for package names, front ::

Tags: r, colors, rstudio, uiappearance

I'm working with R, in RStudio, and I use to specify the package of each function in my scripts, even if the package is already loaded in the environment. I want to be sure that the code will use the `filter()` function from **dplyr**, and not from another package which has a similar named function.

For instance :

[image]

**Question/** to make code easier to read, is there a way to play with global appearance colors, and that package names (all names before `::`) are in a different color (light grey for instance) ?

Comment: You can maybe take a look here, where you can set themes and customise them in rstudio, althought I don't know if you can precise this for package names https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai
From what I know, it's only usable in latest rstudio versions, check this update. https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/10/29/rstudio-ide-custom-theme-support/ 

EDIT : I'm trying at this moment and I don't see a way for my idea to work...

Comment: I found something that works a bit in the way you want it, even if I don't really understand why. In Global option > code > check the highlight R function call. I use the Cobalt theme and on your code it highlight the word dplyr in some ugly green. In combination with my previous comment, I think there is a way to a great solution ! (I love your question and I will surely use the answer too once we figure this out)

Comment: Thank you @Gowachin, I added "Highlight R function call" in the Global options. With my current editor theme (Idle Fingers), it colors in red all R functions (filter, select, max, map), which is not exactly what I was looking for, but it is a very good beginning, as functions and packages have different colors now. I will test other themes, and look at your links.

Comment: With the editor theme "Kr Theme", functions are khaki, and packages lightgreen. Seems good. I will test it during some days.

Comment: I've figured it out (resume in my answer), I think you need to do minor modification to your theme and it could work. I mainly used the web inspector tool in rstudio to figure out what CSS rule is used. The possibility are now unlimited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete answer, I guess will work.

Since a recent version of rstudio, you can add custom themes on rstudio (see this [update blog](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/10/29/rstudio-ide-custom-theme-support/))

From this point you can **create custom themes**, but it require you to know the "code" for each part of your script. After opening the inspector, I've foudn that the `dplyr` word before the `::` is named as `support`. See the color used in the theme Cobalt here ([custom theme editor](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Cobalt)).

Finally, once you created your own theme by modification of a previous one (creating from scratch is always a pain), you **import it** in rstudio (see in the first link) and apply it.

At this point you won't see any change, because you also need to **check Global options > Code > Diplay > highlight R function call**. This will highlight the word classified as `support` and as `support.function`. You can set both colors in the theme editor (Cobalt theme has the first one in light green and the second one in light orange).

I've not done the full process myself but I think it could work.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify themes at this website: https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/local/Monokai

- If you go to **Customize Preview Code** at the bottom right, you can test out the code in your image above.
- If you change the color for **variable**, it seems like this makes the change you're looking for.
- When you've customized everything to your liking, you can download your custom theme. Then you can go back to **Rstudio --> Tools --> Global Options --> Appearance**, and click 'Add' to add your theme.

Comment: Your answer change the color for every variable in the code.
Also I can't manage to customize preview code in a way to precise that `dplyr` word is seen as `support` and not as a variable. Did you managed to do so?